# Submit duplicate form fields as separate rows

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I've rebuild my form to better accommodate what i need it to do. Now I just need to know how to input the values into my database.

My form fields are duplicated as needed and are named form[0][name] so that they can be seen as separate fields. jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/2fDYs.

function;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newNum = 2;
    cloneMe = function(el) {
        var newElem = el.clone().attr('id', 'container' + newNum);
        newElem.children().each(function(index, elem) {
            //$(elem).attr('id', $(elem).attr('id') + newNum).attr('name', $(elem).attr('name')+ newNum);
            var $elem = $(elem);
            $elem.attr('id', $elem.attr('id') + newNum);
            var ename = $elem.attr('name');
            if (ename) {
                $elem.attr('name',ename.replace('form[0]','form['+newNum+']'));
            }
        });
        $('#cloneb').before(newElem);
        $('#delete_name'+ newNum).html('<p id="rem_field"><a href="#"><span>Delete Line</span></a></p>');
        newNum++;
    };

    $('p#rem_field').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('div').remove();
    return false;
});    

});
```

form;

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='form' id='form'>
    <div id="container1">
        <label>Style:</label>
            <select name='form[0][style]' id='style' class='style' onchange="showDim(this)">
                <option value='0' class='red'>Select a style...</option>            
                    <?php
                    include ('connect.php');
                    $getsty = $db->prepare("SELECT Style_ID, Style_Type FROM style ORDER BY Style_Type ASC LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615;"); 
                    $getsty->execute();
                        while($row = $getsty->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {    
                            $Style_ID = $row['Style_ID'];
                            $Style_Type = $row['Style_Type'];                   
                        echo "      <option value='$Style_ID'>$Style_Type</option>";
                        }                                       
                    ?>   
            </select>                                   
        <br />
        <div class='dimdiv'>                    
            <label>Dimensions:</label>
                <select name='form[0][Dim]' id='Dim'>
                    <option value='0' class='red'>Select the dimensions...</option> 
                </select>                       
        </div>
        <br />
        <label>Colour:</label> 
            <select name='form[0][Colour]' id='Colour'>
                <option value='0' class='red'>Select a colour...</option>
                <option value='Colour1'>Colour #1</option>
                <option value='Colour2'>Colour #2</option>
                <option value='Colour3'>Colour #3</option>
                <option value='Colour4'>Colour #4</option>
            </select>
        <br />  
        <label>Quantity:</label> <input type='text' name='form[0][Quantity]' id='Quantity'>
        <br />          
        <div id="delete_name" style="margin:15px 0px 0px 0px; width:120px; height:30px;"></div> 
        <hr />
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="cloneb" value="Clone" onclick="cloneMe($('#container1'));" />
    <input type='submit' name='post' value='Place Order' class='buttons' />
</form>
```

How would I go about inserting each separate 'cloned' form into the database as its own row?

This is as far as i could get with my limited knowledge.

```
<?php               
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_POST as $val){   
            $style = $_POST['form'][$i]['style'];
            $Dim= $_POST['form'][$i]['Dim'];
            $Colour= $_POST['form'][$i]['Colour'];
            $Quantity= $_POST['form'][$i]['Quantity'];

    include ('connect.php');    

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO details(Style, Dimensions, Colour, Quantity) VALUES(:Style,:Dimensions,:Colour,:Quantity)");

    $stmt->execute(array(':Style' => $Style, ':Dimensions' => $Dim, ':Colour' => $Colour, ':Quantity' => $Quantity));     

        $i++;
        } 
    }           
?>
```

EDIT: The values entered in to the database are all the same except the 'style' field. They all take on the values of the last duplicated form.

Comment: So, what is wrong with your code?

Comment: the values entered in to the database are all the same bar the 'style' field. They all take on the values of the last duplicated form.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code is not working, that's why you are receiving only one row.

Instead of iterating over children, you can edit new element content.

```
var newElem = el.clone().attr('id', 'container' + newNum);
newElem.html(newElem.html().replace(/form\[0\]/g, 'form['+newNum+']'));
newElem.html(newElem.html().replace(/id="(.*?)"/g, 'id="1'+newNum+'"'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fMSa3/1/

Comment: Hmm, I've tried replacing my `var newElem` with your suggestion and it breaks the ability to clone the form. Am I replacing the wrong part?

Comment: @RathBaloth Updated with fiddle.

Comment: It's shooting back `unidentified index` for each form field now, with the modified html too the php I'm using to echo the values doesn't work, it just refreshes the page

Comment: The PHP was what I was originally asking about, how should this be changed? Also when I use var_dump only the 1st 'Dim' value is shown (Other values are fine for all clones), any other 'Dim' values seem to not be passed on.

Comment: The var dump shows this when I clone only once to have '2' forms; `array (size=2)'form' => array (size=3)0 =>  array (size=3)'style' => string '3' (length=1)'Colour' => string 'Colour1' (length=7)'Quantity' => string '10' (length=2)1 => array (size=1)'Dim' => string '5' (length=1)2 => array (size=3)'style' => string '4' (length=1)'Colour' => string 'Colour2' (length=7)'Quantity' => string '20' (length=2)'post' => string 'Submit' (length=11)` There is a missing 2nd Dim array at the bottom, these Dim array need to be part of the array with the other 3 fields in.